# Prometheus scarpe json data from python script

Tags: json, prometheus

Thank you first,
I have a question about Prometheus and JSON,
in my case that I have a python script to monitor my device (camera), and after that it returns JSON data, but my problem that when it returns JSON data I don't know how to input it to Prometheus.
I don't know which methods or keywords I should use in my case, because it will monitoring around 100 devices.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Start from one example https://www.metricfire.com/blog/how-to-monitor-python-applications-with-prometheus/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please see [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).